# PHP to draw out tree / org chart like of data

Tags: php

I have a database which have this fields

```
username
placement
position
```

Lets say username have 4 person

```
Jimmy
Peter
John
Mary
```

Jimmy is the head of the tree

```
On Jimmy Left Branch is Peter, on Jimmy Right Branch is Mary
On Mary Right Branch is John
```

So its like

```
Jimmy
> Peter
> Mary
  > John
```

How do I do it for N amount of user, until all the tree is draw out nicely.

Because my code structure is like

```
<ul id="organisation">
                <li>Jimmy
                    <ul>
                        <li>Peter</li>
                        <li>Mary
                            <ul>
                                <li>John</li></ul></li>
                     </ul></li></ul>


Jimmy <li> tag will be open, and close </li> when his branch is done.
```

My database have this field which is placement and position, such as for John, Placement is Mary, and position is Right

How do I do the logic to ensure all the user and echo are done properly, this logic is very complicated. Anyone can enlighten me?

**Thanks for helping**

Comment: You should save the tree level

Comment: @LLL , what is save the tree level?

Comment: How do you know your tree struct from your database?